# Image not showing within div

Tags: html, css

My Divs are aligned perfectly. I am trying to add an image in the center div but as soon as I add the image the divs disappear and the image is not showing. 
I am having the issue with adding the image, can someone please assist. Why is my image not showing whats wrong with my code?

```css
<style>

.div_parent{

    display:inline;
background-image: url('../images/image.jpg') top center no-repeat;"

  }
  
.div_center {


  width:300px;
  float:left;
  border-color:black; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:3px;
  height :700px
}

.div_right
 {
  background-color:#edeeef; 
  border-color:black; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:3px; 
  width: 150px;
  float:left;
  height:100%
}
.div_left
 {
  background-color:#edeeef; 
  border-color:black; 
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:3px; 
  width: 150px;
  float:left;
  height:100%
}


</style>
```

```html
<div class="div_parent">


<div class="div_left">
 <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
       <FONT size="3" style="font-family:sans-serif ; color:red; text-align:center;" > <STRONG>Welcome to the Reporting Portal! </STRONG> </font><br />
       <br />
      <FONT size="2" style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align: left;"> 
     Reports on this site are available as view-only or as an Excel download. </font>
</div>
<div class="div_center">   


</div>

<div class="div_right">
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<FONT size="3" style="font-family:sans-serif ; color:red; text-align:center;" > <STRONG> We're Here to Help! </STRONG> </font><br /><br />
       
<FONT size="2" style="font-family:sans-serif; text-align:left;"> 
We're friendly and available to chat. Reach out to us anytime and we'll happily answer your questions.</br><br />
Supervisors should submit requests including specific fields and search criteria to us at Report Manager</a></font>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want them aligned? same height? one div under the other when width is too small for both and float them left?

Comment: I want them aligned 1----2-----3  two sides one should be like 15px each and the middle one should be the widest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this out?

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.element__left, 
.element__right, 
.element__center {
    height: 50px;
}
.element__left, .element__right  {
     width: 25%;
     float: left;
     background-color: grey;
}
.element__center {
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
     background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element__left">
  <div class="element__center">
  <div class="element__right">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for assisting. I want the green one to be in the center and has the most widht and the other two to be in the sides with same width. When i run the code snippet, the green one is aligned on the left side and the other two grey ones have are different in size.

Comment: I see your point and in fact by running the code straight away in the browser worked fine. Even the solution down here seems pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.divOuter{
        display:inline;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .divInner1{
        border: 1px solid;
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-right:3px;
    }
.divInner2{
        border: 1px solid;
        float:left;
        width:250px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-right:3px;
    }
.divInner3{
        border: 1px solid;
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-right:3px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class='divOuter'>
    <div class='divInner1'>First DIV</div>
    <div class='divInner2'>Second DIV</div>
    <div class='divInner3'>Third DIV</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, I dont know why but when use the same exact code that you provided which seems to be working accurately, all my divs are aligned vertically instead of side by side.

Comment: Did you apply my code or doing any wrong please check properly

Comment: yeah I have double checked everything

Answer (score 1):

Lets try following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="not-ie" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>aligning 3 divs with different widthst</title>
<style type="text/css">
    * { padding:0; margin:0;}
    body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff; font-    size:16px;}
    .div_parent { position:relative; width:100%; height:300px; overflow:auto; line-height:300px; text-align:center;}

    .div_left { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; height:100%; background-color:#900; width:150px;}
    .div_middle { position:absolute; left:150px; right:150px; top:0; height:100%; overflow:auto; background-color:#00F;}
    .div_right { position:absolute; right:0; top:0; height:100%; background-color:#900; width:150px;}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div_parent">
        <div class="div_left">width: 100px;</div>
        <div class="div_middle">width: screen - 200px;</div>
        <div class="div_right">width: 100px;</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my whole page is blank :(